# how to call async with while loop with Api?

Tags: javascript, function, api, response

I am calling my API in a While loop 4 times. The first time I got a response from the API. then after API response goes to infinity. So How to Call API While loop to get a response in all 4 times?

Thanks in Advance

```
export const getMeal = () => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'MEAL_IN_PROGRESS' });
        let i: number = 1; 
            while (i < 4) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    ApiInternalService.get(ApiRoutes.getMeal, (response, _error) => {
                        console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", i);
                        console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
                        console.log(response.results[0]);
                        if (response && response.results && response.results[0]) {
                            tmpArray.push(response.results[0]);
                        }

                        if (i === 4) {
                            console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                            dispatch({ type: 'MEAL_SUCCESS', payload: tmpArray })
                        }

                        i++
                        // Alert.alert("Don't get Response from Api");
                        // i += 1;
                    })
                    setTimeout(1500)
                }, 1500)
            }





    };
};
```

Comment: Apologies, it is not entirely clear what the problem is. What is happening that should not be happening? Have a skim over [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you should see a better response

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use Promise instead of setTimeout().
Please google "Promise in Javascript" to learn and Implement.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is running indefinitely is because you're incrementing `i` inside the promise resolve function and not inside while loop. Hence, it is running indefinetely. You can solve it by replacing it with for loop.

You can also use `Promise.all()` for resolving multiple promises

```
export const getMeal = () => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'MEAL_IN_PROGRESS' });
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          //
        }
```